# How Do I Stop A Repeater In Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, timer, vibration

Ok, so I have an app that vibrates constantly using a Timer when I press a button. and I have another button that I want to use to stop it from vibrating. but also able to enable again with the start button. How should I do this? Here is my code(button2 is the stop button)(also im using xcode):

```
@IBAction func button1(_ sender: UIButton) {
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate)
    _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.0, target: self, 
        selector: Selector(("doaction")), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

@IBAction func button2(_ sender: UIButton) {
}
```

Comment: You can't do it. You didn't keep any reference to the Timer (you assigned it to `_`) so you can't invalidate it. That was a pretty silly thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

Add a timer property to your class:

```
var timer: Timer?
```

Then update your two methods:

```
@IBAction func button1(_ sender: UIButton) {
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate)
    timer?.invalidate()
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.0, target: self, 
        selector: Selector(("doaction")), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

@IBAction func button2(_ sender: UIButton) {
    timer?.invalidate()
    timer = nil
}
```

By making use of the timer property, you can access the timer from any method in your class.